Whether and how to fit a GAM with a Gamma distribution in R
I would like to fit GAMs using elevation as a predictor and chemical concentration as a response in R via the gam() function in mgcv with a Gamma distribution.  However, using gam(..., bs = "cs", family = Gamma(link = "log"), method = "REML", data = dat) results in a flat line fit at zero
(Fig. 1,ag2_p <- predict_gam(ag_gam2) ag2_p %>% ggplot(aes(elevation, fit)) + geom_smooth_ci()+ geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = alpha.guaiene, x =elevation))+ theme_classic()), whereas a Gaussian distribution (which, I believe is inappropriate for concentration data) results is what looks like a reasonable fit (Fig. 2, ag1_p1 <- predict_gam(ag_gam1) ag1_p1 %>% ggplot(aes(elevation, fit)) + geom_smooth_ci()+ geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = alpha.guaiene, x =elevation))+ theme_classic()). The script for the latter is gam(..., bs = "cs", family = gaussian(link = "identity"), method = "REML", data = dat)
I suspect that the problem may be in the plot script rather than the model, as the gamma model looks quite decent in when I call plot(mod) as seen on the right-hand side of Fig. 3 (whereas the Gaussian is on the left) but I don't know what the problem would be.
My questions are:
(1) Is the syntax that I am using for the Gamma distribution correct?
(2) Is the Gamma distribution indeed more appropriate for these data
(3) If the answers to 1 and 2 are yes, why am I getting such a terrible fit with the Gamma model?




Does predict_gam return predictions on the "link" (log for Gamma) scale? Seems that you're plotting data and predictions on different scales for your "ag_gam2" model

@alexis_laz I was not able to determine that from the function documentation, but that seems quite possible. Do you have any sense of how else I could determine that?

The simplest thing is to look at the y-axis of ag2_p %>% ggplot(aes(elevation, fit)). You could also check the function source (type predict_gam in the console and locate where it calls some lower level prediction function from the "mgcv" package; e.g. it could be using predict.gam(..., type = "link")) for a clearer view of what's happening.

@JKO it does predict on the link scale by default (see the argument type in ?predict.gam which defaults to the value "link").

@GavinSimpson, I'm using predict_gam here (not predict.gam), which only allows type =  "link" or "terms".

@JKO, well that's the problem, the link scale is the log scale here so you need to exponentiate everything.
